# DISTINCT for single column Using Row_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've MSSQL Query with DISTINCT and ROW_NUMBER(),

QUERY IS:

```
    SELECT * from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY  b.tc_priority ) AS row,
DISTINCT a.tc_id 
from release_details a, tc_details b 
where a.tc_id=b.tc_name 
and 
tst_system is null 
and release_name='sdkfei' 
and tenv_id='32' 
and env_id='32' 
and tst_type='21' 
and b.autotech='ITL' 
and a.project=b.project 
and a.project='JupiterQA' 
and depclosed=1) AS tab12
 WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

ERROR IS:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'

Is anything wrong with this query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY  b.tc_priority  AS row,
 a.tc_id 
from release_details a, tc_details b and then where condition (......)

Comment: DISTINCT works on the entire row, not a specific column